# Why is this question about LaTeX posters being closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, closed-questions

[Comparison: umbcposter vs baposter vs tikzposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269296/32888) has been closed as a duplicate of [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/32888).

I don't think the question is a duplicate. The answers in [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/32888) mostly just provide a list of the different packages that you could use to make a poster. There is hardly any discussion of how they work, much less a comparison of the various options.

I voted to reopen, but I've noticed that a lot of people have been voting to keep the question closed. I'm curious what the rationale is.

I could understand the question being closed as being too broad or opinion-based (but even then, I'm not so sure; but that would at least make more sense to me than being a duplicate).

I really don't understand how it is a duplicate of [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/32888).

So two questions, I guess:

1. Why is this closed as a duplicate; why are people voting to keep it closed?
2. If there isn't a good reason for keeping it closed as a duplicate, shouldn't it be reopened?

Comment: I voted the last one for reopening but still question is a pretty boring and almost unanswerable. At least it should have been closed as opinion based because one man's disadvantage is another ones feature.

Comment: @percusse I agree. At the very least, it's quite clearly not a duplicate as far as I can tell.